# Auto width with the help of CSS (or JQuery?)

Tags: jquery, css

I have a bunch of `<li>` nodes that need to float left.  The total sum of the width of these nodes when float left are larger than their parent container.  Instead of the width of the parent node increasing, the `<li>` expand the height of the parent and essentially flow down to the next line.

Is there a CSS solution to this issue or will I need a jQuery script to alter the size of the parent node based on how many children are in it?

Comment: Could you make a quick jsfiddle with an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a CSS solution.  You can accomplish it with jQuery as you suggest though.

Comment: Yeah...I kinda figured.  Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm 100% clear on what the issue is and what problem you would like to solve, but with only CSS:

You can keep the li's from stretching the height of the parent if you set a height on the parent equal to the height of the li's.

An overflow:hidden; on the parent might also be desired, unless you want scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're asking, but maybe not. Check this out. I went overboard on the CSS, but it just illustrates the point. [**Here's a Fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/Cb8jR/2/)

```
<div class="navItems">
    <div class="navOutline">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
            <!-- Add more items and it'll expand -->
            <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.navItems ul { list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; }
.navItems li { display:inline; }
.navItems li:not(:last-child) { margin-right:10px }
.navItems .bumper { margin-right:15px; }
.navItems {
    float:left;
    font-size:14px;    
    padding:5px;
    background:#FFF;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -o-box-shadow:0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -ms-box-shadow:0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
.navOutline {
    margin:auto auto;
    padding:10px;
    background:#FFF;
    border:1px dashed #CCC;
}
.navItems a { text-decoration:none; color:#000; }​
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  I'm down with all the css, except the `<ul>` resides in a `<div>` with no defined width, but that node's parent has a defined width.  The problem is when the `<li>`'s float left, the width is being inherited from the "grandparent" node.

Comment: Would a clearfix address this issue? (http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) Floated elements kind of exist outside of the flow of the DOM, so their heights and widths are not taken into consideration.

Comment: No, I always use a ghost `clear` div not matter what.  The issue isn't necessarily with the float itself, but with the size of the parent container.  It's also all inside a Joomla template which has it's own defined widths.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate parent of the floated elements should have `display:inline-block` property.

Comment: If you check this [link](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/), and go to the, "why is sucks," part, you'll get what I mean.

Comment: You asked for a CSS solution, and that's it. Dealing with cross-browser issues (IE7 an prior) it's something totally different.

Comment: The inherent flaw in this method is the issue I'm dealing with.  You just re-iterated my problem.  If you look at the link I gave you, it's under the heading,"The Enormous Drawback".  chill.